# messages - AppleScript send image on macOS 12

Tags: applescript, message, macos-monterey

So I have this AppleScript

```
set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "photo.png"

tell application "Messages"
    set targetService to 1st account whose service type = iMessage
    set targetBuddy to participant "+18005555555" of targetService
    send file filePath to targetBuddy
end tell
```

worked before but in macOS 12 it looks like it's working (see the progress bar) but eventually timesout and states it can't be sent.

Is there an update to sending this?

Comment: Does Messages contain a pre-existing chat between you and "+18005555555" ?

Comment: @CJK In my own testing (same issue as OP), the issue exists regardless of if there is an existing conversation.

Comment: @Questionmark, that's not why I was asking.